# Row-granularity operations/error handling

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have read many articles and posts about how a cursor is a massive performance hindrance over the equivalent single set query.

However, with a cursor, you are able to perform the desired operation successfully on all rows that did not err, and provide an error message for each row that did.

Is there some other way I can achieve this row granularity with set operations?

Comment: In T-SQL, no. That's why ETL processes commonly perform RBAR validations and transformations in client code, loading happy path data into staging tables with a bulk load method for the final set-based load via T-SQL.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis . . . It depends on what the operations are.  For data transformations, a cursor is almost never necessary.  You do need cursors (or something similar) for things like executing a stored procedure on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a set-based operations works - as the name tells us - with a set. It will work or fail in total.

A `CURSOR` (or any other procedural approach like `WHILE` or an external program) can be the best choice in this case.

If performance matters I would prefer to use a tolerant staging table for the first set based import. Then do some quality/cleaning actions there to ensure the succesfull transfer and shift the cleaned data into your target tables (set based).

This depends on the data, your business rules and - of course - the amount of rows.